# Error deploying to AWS EB: SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am unable to deploy any Django app to AWS EB

I am following this tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html), installed certifi package

```py
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

'/Users/mitchellmurphy/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'

eb deploy throws the following error:
ERROR: URLError [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>

eb open should pull up a blank Django starter app, instead I get a "Internal Server Error"

Also adding the --no-verify-ssl flag to all my eb commands...

Comment: Where is `eb` installed? Try `which eb`. If it's installed in some virtual environment, make sure that one has that package too. Also, why do you think `eb deploy` certificate error is related to your `Internal Server Error`? After it's deployed, it's deployed. Check the logs for the real error.

Comment: I apologize, that error was not thrown by eb deploy, rather after when I ran eb logs. EB was not installed in a virtual environment. I simply copied cacert.pem to cert.pem and was able to successfully deploy!